# How to include alpha characters in this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a tough time with this regex. Basically I have a phone formatter and thats seems to work ok as long as the telephone numbers do not contain any alpha characters. For example 800THENAME if anyone has any advice or suggestions I would be grateful. Below please find a code example.

```
let formatted = phone.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
return (!formatted) ? null : "(" + formatted[1] + ") " + formatted[2] + "-" + m[3];
```

The above code will return (800)123-456 but there is alph characters it comes up as undefined

Comment: Can you add examples and what is acceptable and whats not.

Comment: Validating and formatting should be separate concerns. Simplistically, you could just use `/^(.{3})(.{3})(.{4})$/` or validate first then split using *substr* or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick

```
let formatted = phone.match(/^(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{4})$/);
```

Comment: `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @GalacticRanger You should use `/^([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9]{4})$/i` to avoid matching `_` in the string.